# Event listener not working on Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, events, listener

I have implemented an event listener for auditing operations over my entities. For example, I made one for PreInsertEventListener called HibernatePreInsert. Also, by reading here on stackoverflow I configured an Integrator called HibernateIntegrator. Since I'm using Hibernate 4 and spring 4, I created a file under META-INF/services named com.dacasals.raspertwo.interceptors.HibernateInterceptor and there I added the integrator class, as recommended over the web and also here. But when I run my application and insert a new element, nothing happens, not even the messages of my HibernatePrePersist are displayed. This is the first time I try Hibernate EventListeners and I don't know what could be wrong.

Here is and example of the classes involved in my problem, also the file structure:

The listener:

```
public class HibernatePreInsert implements PreInsertEventListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernatePreInsert.class);

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
        if(event.getEntity() instanceof Person){
            //display a message to know if this works or not
            logger.info("It works");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The Integrator:

```
public class HibernateIntegrator implements Integrator{

    public void integrate(Configuration configuration, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry){
        final EventListenerRegistry registry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

        HibernatePreInsert listener = new HibernatePreInsert();

        registry.prependListeners(EventType.PRE_INSERT, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

The file com.dacasals.raspertwo.interceptors.HibernateInterceptor:

```
com.dacasals.raspertwo.interceptors.HibernateInterceptor
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED:**
I made a mistake while writing. I'm using Hibernate 5, not 4.

Comment: What is the goal of your listener?  Are you wanting to set values on the entity itself or are you wanting to insert a row in another table?

Comment: I want to store in my database information about the event executed. For example if a new Person is inserted, I wan to save the timestamp of the operation executed. I was trying to do that simple example on the onPreInsert method but nothing happened, then I displayed a message and realize nothing was happening.

Comment: I assume you're just importing the `hibernate-core` dependency with Hibernate 4 and not using the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency and working with a `SessionFactory`.  Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I'm using maven to solve my dependencies. On my pom.xml I have both hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager as you can see here: 

`<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>5.2.3.Final</version>`

`<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.7.Final</version>`

And I made a mistake, I'm using Hibernate 5 not 4.

Comment: For version 5.2, you no longer need the `hibernate-entitymanager` artifact.  It was merged into `hibernate-core` for you.  What factory is your configuration building by chance, a `SessionFactory` or `EntityManagerFactory` ?

Comment: SessionFactory, that's the one I use on my DAO's to persist, update and delete Person(for example)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got my listeners to work without using the method I found before. Instead of defining a file with the service, I created a new class where I register my implemented Event Listeners like this:

```
@Component
public class EscuchadorGeneral {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Inject
    private InsertEvent insert;

    @Inject
    private UpdateEvent update;

    @Inject
    private DeleteEvent delete;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init(){
        SessionFactoryImpl sF = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sF.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_INSERT).appendListener(insert);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE).appendListener(update);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_DELETE).appendListener(delete);
    }

}
```

And now I can listen when any of my entities is inserted, updated or deleted. I hope this solution works for other developers too.

Answer (score 3):

Since all you're wanting to do is to manipulate the entity associated to the event, I would advocate the usage of `@PrePersist` here.

You can fool Hibernate to still fire the JPA integrator callbacks even when the application doesn't use any JPA features and continues to use the native `SessionFactory` configuration.

For Hibernate prior to 5.2, you would need to make sure that you also include the appropriate versioned `hibernate-entitymanager` on your dependency classpath that matches the same version of your `hibernate-core` dependency.  For Hibernate 5.2 and beyond, all you need to include is `hibernate-core`, which you obviously already use.

Next is to setup `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`.

For Hibernate prior to 4.2 you need to add:

> org.hibernate.ejb.event.JpaIntegrator

For Hibernate 4.3 and 5.x, you need to add:

> org.hibernate.jpa.event.spi.JpaIntegrator

You should now be able to use the `@PrePersist` callback even when your configuration does not bootstrap a JPA `EntityManager`.

Then as you port your application to using JPA specifically, you can eventually remove this integrator configuration as a JPA built `EntityManager` will automatically register and execute these callbacks.

**UPDATE**

Should you decide you want to use a Hibernate `EventListener`, I would make sure both `integrate` methods register that listener.  I think the one you've implemented was left for legacy contracts but I believe the later versions of Hibernate use the other signature specifically that you haven't yet implemented.  That could be why your listener doesn't fire.

Comment: I will search for the implementation of the second `integrate` method. I read your answer, and I have tried the annotations approach, but I don' t need it this time. I'm trying to do this using the EvenListeners.